# webpage got freeze (browser message: page unresponsive) when doubleclick on leaflet map many times to show nearby resturants

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, freeze

I'm using a leaflet map with reactJs, The purpose of it is that when I double-click on a specific location the lat & lng of where I double-clicked are sent to API to bring nearby restaurants then I show them as markers on the map, If I do it more than 3 times the page freeze and browser says page unresponsive, I think it is memory leak issue.

```
let vendorMarkerIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: markerIconPng,
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [12, 41],
});

export const PureMapDrow = () => {

const [markerPosition, setMarkerPosition] = useState(null);

  const { isLoading: loading, data } = useQuery(
    [
      "getVendorsOnMap",
      markerPosition && markerPosition[0],
      markerPosition && markerPosition[1],
    ],
    getVendorsOnMap,
    {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      retry: 2,
      enabled: markerPosition !== null,
    }
  );

  const MapComponent = () => {
    const map = useMap();

    useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(function () {
        map.invalidateSize();
      }, 100);
    }, [isCreateModal, polygon]);

    map.on("dblclick", (e) => {
      map.panTo(new L.latLng(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng));
      setMarkerPosition([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]);
    });

    return null;
  };

  

  return (
    <div>
      <Spin spinning={loading}>
        <MapContainer
          center={[33.3152, 44.3661]}
          zoomControl={false}
          zoom={10}
          scrollWheelZoom={true}
          attributionControl={false}
          style={{ height: "500px" }}
        >
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          {markerPosition && ( //when I double-click I set lat & lon to markerPosition state 
            <Marker position={markerPosition} icon={vendorMarkerIcon} />
          )}
          {data &&
            data?.data &&
            data.success &&
            data?.data?.map((el, index) => (
              <Marker
                key={index}
                position={[el.lat, el.lon]}
                icon={L.icon({
                  className: "marker",
                  iconUrl: el.logoImg || markerIconPng,
                  iconSize: [40, 40],
                })}
              >
                <Popup>{el.arName}</Popup>
              </Marker>
            ))}
          <MapComponent />
        </MapContainer>
      </Spin>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I try to use useMemo with my component (PureMapDrow) and it still the same

Comment: Look for infinite loops, that's what causes page to freeze. E.g. `setTimeout` is never cancelled, even if `useEffect` is called few times in short interval.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be creating a component _within_ a component.

Comment: @Justinas the only way to trigger ` setTimeout ` is  ` isCreateModal ` or ` polygon ` states  and both are not changed if I double-click on the map